# How to sum 3 same sized sorted lists based on the identical elements of the first one in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sum, iteration

I have a python `dictionary` containing 3 `lists` in the keys 'time', 'power' and 'usage'.
All the lists have the same number of elements and all the lists are sorted. What
I want to do is to sum up all the elements for lists 'power' and 'usage' that their indexes
correspond to the same value in list 'time', so as to have only one sample of power and usage per time unit.

For example transform this dictionary:

```
{'time': [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5],
 'power': [2, 2, 3, 6, 3, 3, 2],
 'usage': [0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 7]}
```

to this one:

```
{'time': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 'power': [2, 5, 6, 6, 2],
 'usage': [0, 2, 2, 5, 7]}
```

Already I have written this piece of code that works but I don't like
it so much:

```
d = {'time':[1,2,2,3,4,4,5], 'power':[0,1,1,2,1,4,7], 'usage':[2,2,3,6,3,3,2]}
prev = -1
new_d = {'time':[], 'power': [], 'usage':[]}
indexes =  range( len(d['time']) )

for i in indexes:
  if d['time'][i]!=prev:
    new_d['time'].append(d['time'][i])
    new_d['power'].append(d['power'][i])
    new_d['usage'].append(d['usage'][i])
  else:
    last_power = len( new_d['power'] ) - 1
    last_usage = len( new_d['usage'] ) - 1
    new_d['power'][last_power]+=d['power'][i]
    new_d['usage'][last_usage]+=d['usage'][i]
  prev=d['time'][i]

print d
print new_d
```

Is there a pythonian way to do this more simply and comprehensive?

Comment: Actually I have a dictionary with 20 different lists with more information of power and usage..

Comment: Not all the lists are sorted =P. Or at least `power` and `usage` seem to have strange some strange criterion. It look more like you have tuples `(time, power, usage)` stored as named lists. They are sorted via `time` field and you want to compress it. But it's still understanable. If I got everything right, lol. Also Do you want to `sum` all other fields too ?

Comment: You're doing it wrong.  You should have one list of objects, each of which has `time`, `power`, and `usage` fields (and your other 20 fields).  That will make your code much simpler, clearer, and more Pythonic, and will make processing _much_ easier.

Comment: Are you going to accept an answer? Or has your question not been solved yet? Please let me know if there is something wrong.

Comment: Your answer is very good, but I looked for something more simple and comprehensive. And I found it at jamylak's answer. I have added to his answer the code that works for multiple fields. Look at the end the "Thanasis Petsas' edits"

Comment: Please do not edit others answers. Instead, either post your own answer adapted from others, or add your implementation as an edit to your original post and accept the answer that helped you most.

Comment: ok! you have right! I'll do so. But, I haven't chosen yet which is the best! I am doing some tests right now!

Comment: In that case, I suggest you look at the `timeit` module that comes with Python. And run a series of tests that will check for the best solution based on your actual data, or on a matrix of data, ie: many fields->few fields, many duplicates->few duplicates.. and all in between. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> d = {'usage': [0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 7], 'power': [2, 2, 3, 6, 3, 3, 2], 'time': [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]}
>>> groups = groupby(zip(d['time'], d['power'], d['usage']), key=itemgetter(0))
>>> lists = zip(*[[k] + map(sum, zip(*g)[1:]) for k, g in groups])
>>> dict(zip(('time', 'power', 'usage'), lists))
{'usage': (0, 2, 2, 5, 7), 'power': (2, 5, 6, 6, 2), 'time': (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)}
```

For variable number of keys, I've added the `keys` variable to avoid having to rewrite them:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> keys = ('time', 'power', 'usage')
>>> groups = groupby(zip(*[d[k] for k in keys]), key=itemgetter(0))
>>> lists = zip(*[[k] + map(sum, zip(*g)[1:]) for k, g in groups])
>>> dict(zip(keys, lists))
{'usage': (0, 2, 2, 5, 7), 'power': (2, 5, 6, 6, 2), 'time': (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)}
```

Comment: I am not sure about this method, because first of all you have no way to be certain that you connect the right key to the right list. And I have the feeling this will increase in complexity the more fields there are.. but I am not sure.

Comment: @InbarRose Everything is completely certain in this method. The order of the keys determines that. I could easily adapt this for more fields too, I would just make a `keys` variable so I wouldn't have to write each one twice

Comment: @jamylak I am interested to see how this would look as a method after you scale it to work with x fields.

Comment: Ok, I did it by myself. Your answer helped me to do exactly what I wanted to! I have add to your answer the code adapted to multiple fields! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

A robust solution that can handle any number of extra fields - sorted by the 'time' field (as a method):

```
def aggregate(old_d, sort_key='time'):
    new_d = dict((k, []) for k in old_d)
    prev = None
    curr = None
    for i in range(len(old_d[sort_key])):
        curr = old_d[sort_key][i]
        for key, lst in new_d.iteritems(): # .items() in Python 3+
            if prev == curr:
                if key != sort_key:           
                    lst[-1] += old_d[key][i]
            else:
                lst.append(old_d[key][i])
        prev = curr
    return new_d
```

Using your dictionary:

```
d = {'time': [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5],
     'power': [2, 2, 3, 6, 3, 3, 2],
     'usage': [0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 7]}

print aggregate(d)
>>>
{'usage': [0, 2, 2, 5, 7], 'power': [2, 5, 6, 6, 2], 'time': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
```

Comment: Yes, ok. This way seems more coprehensive than mine.

Comment: @ThanasisPetsas Edited my answer to provide a robust solution to any arbitrary sized dict.

Comment: Edited it again to be more clear on what is going on, and improved efficiency by iterating over the new_d.

Comment: I run your code with my real data and I got an `IndexError`:
    `lst[-1] += old_d[key][i]`
    `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Then your lists are not the same length as you originally stated.

Comment: Yes right, my bad! I have a bug in my code. Your solution works great, but jamylak's was nearer to what I wanted, so I accepted his answer..

Answer (score 3):

Here's one that will handle arbitrary dictionaries.... (where `d` is your dict...)

```
from itertools import groupby, imap
from operator import itemgetter

def group_dict_by(mapping, field, agg=sum):
    grouper = mapping[field]
    new_grouper = []
    accum = {k: [] for k in mapping.viewkeys() - [field]}
    for key, grp in groupby(enumerate(grouper), itemgetter(1)):
        new_grouper.append(key)
        idx = [g[0] for g in grp]   
        for dk, dv in accum.iteritems():
            dv.append(agg(imap(mapping[dk].__getitem__, idx)))

    accum[field] = new_grouper
    return accum

print group_dict_by(d, 'time')
# {'usage': [0, 2, 2, 5, 7], 'power': [2, 5, 6, 6, 2], 'time': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
```

Comment: This is almost exactly the same as the answer I cooked up but decided not to post.  Of course, I hard-coded `field` and `agg`, and I used a `defaultdict(list)` rather than a normal dict (setting `out.default_factory = None` before I returned.

Answer (score 2):

Using `itertools.groupby`, `zip` and some list comprehensions:

```
In [55]: dic={'time': [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5],
   ....:  'power': [2, 2, 3, 6, 3, 3, 2],
   ....:  'usage': [0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 7]}

In [56]: from itertools import groupby

In [57]: from operator import itemgetter

In [58]: zip1=zip(dic['time'],dic['power']) #use `itertools.izip` for performance    

In [59]: [sum(x[1] for x in v) for k,v in groupby(zip1,key=itemgetter(0))]
Out[59]: [2, 5, 6, 6, 2]

In [60]: zip2=zip(dic['time'],dic['usage'])

In [61]: [sum(x[1] for x in v) for k,v in groupby(zip2,key=itemgetter(0))]
Out[61]: [0, 2, 2, 5, 7]

In [64]: timee=[k for k,v in groupby(dic['time'])]

In [65]: timee
Out[65]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

`zip1` is `[(1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 6), (4, 3), (4, 3), (5, 2)]`, now you can group elements based on the first item using `itertools.groupby` and then take the sum of the second element of each tuple in the returned group.

```
In [75]: new_time=[k for k,v in groupby(dic['time'])]

In [76]: new_power=[sum(x[1] for x in v) for k,v in groupby(zip1,key=itemgetter(0))]

In [77]: new_usage=[sum(x[1] for x in v) for k,v in groupby(zip2,key=itemgetter(0))]

In [80]: dict(zip(('time','power','usage'),(new_time,new_power,new_usage)))
Out[80]: {'power': [2, 5, 6, 6, 2], 'time': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'usage': [0, 2, 2, 5, 7]}
```

Comment: I am not really sure what you are doing here. Where is the the new dict?

Comment: @InbarRose You can get the required dict by simply assigning those list comprehension to a new dict.

Comment: This whole thing seems like it will not scale easily, and it gives me a headache trying to understand the code with all the [in/out] going on.... blegh! But yes, the answer is correct. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following method for an arbitrary number of extra fields:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

dic = {'time': [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5],
 'power': [2, 2, 3, 6, 3, 3, 2],
 'usage': [0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 7]}

aggrigated = {}
fields = dic.items()

for field in fields:
    aggrigated[field[0]] = [sum(y[1] for y in x)
                                for k,x in groupby(
                                    zip(fields[0][1], field[1]), 
                                    key=itemgetter(0))
                           ]
```

Improved version borrowing from Ashwini Chaudhary's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would first group the values in a new dict and then sum then. Takes a bit more space but it's easy and fast:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import groupby

power = defaultdict(list)
usage = defaultdict(list)

for i, time in enumerate(data['time']):
    power[time].append(data['power'][i])
    usage[time].append(data['usage'][i])

times = [key for key,group in groupby(data['time'])]

print {    'time': times,
           'power' : [sum(power[time]) for time in times],
           'usage' : [sum(usage[time]) for time in times]
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import izip

def m_(time, power, usage):

    time_, power_, usage_ = [], [], []

    for t, p, u in izip(time, power, usage):

        if not time_:
            time_.append( t )
            power_.append( 0 )
            usage_.append( 0 )

        if time_[-1] == t:
            power_[-1] += p
            usage_[-1] += u
        else:
            time_.append( t )
            power_.append( p )
            usage_.append( u )

    time[:], power[:], usage[:] = time_, power_, usage_

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = {'time':[1,2,2,3,4,4,5], 'power':[0,1,1,2,1,4,7], 'usage':[2,2,3,6,3,3,2]}
    m_(**d)
    print d
```

Comment: Yes, very nice looking method, but can you scale it?

Answer (score 0):

This is the "pythonian way" :) :

```
d = {'time': [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5],
 'power': [2, 2, 3, 6, 3, 3, 2],
 'usage': [0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 7]}

new_d = {'time' : [], 'power' : [], 'usage' : []}

for time in set(d['time']):
    new_d['time'].append(time)
    new_d['power'].append(sum(value for index, value in enumerate(d['power']) if d['time'][index] == time)) 
    new_d['usage'].append(sum(value for index, value in enumerate(d['usage']) if d['time'][index] == time))

print new_d
```

Comment: This is not going to be faster. For every `time`, you look up each list of `power` and `usage` .. that is a lot of over head.

Comment: Cool! And I think I can easily iterate through dictionary keys and do this, as my real data is a dictionary with 20 lists, not only 3! :)

Comment: Yes, it's easily scalable.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the precise solution to my problem. I made it based on the answer of jamylak
which I think is the most "pythonian" and comprehensive solution of all given. What I
have done is to adapt his code so as to work with multiple fields, that is multiple
lists in a dictionary. I have accepted the answer of jamylak and here is the **solution
for multiple fields:**

```
from itertools import groupby              
from operator import itemgetter

d = {'power': [2, 2, 3, 6, 3, 3, 2],
     'usage': [0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 7],
     'time': [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]}

# construct a list with all the key names (starting from 'time')
keys = ['time'] + [key for key in d.keys() if key!='time']
# construct a list with all the keys' lists (starting from the one of 'time')
keys_lists = [ d['time'] ] + [d[key] for key in d.keys() if key!='time']
groups = groupby(zip(*keys_lists), key=itemgetter(0))
lists = zip(*[[k] + map(sum, zip(*g)[1:]) for k, g in groups])
new_d = dict(zip((keys), lists))
print new_d
```